# Different Source and Destination IP to and from ISP

Tags: isp, route

Could somebody tell me which model the ISP are using ?

I have a leasedline WAN with following information.

```
IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.123
Gateway: XXX.XXX.XXX.126
Subnet: 255.255.255.248
```

The problem is every packet send out my router is come to ISP gateway(XXX.XXX.XXX.126) but the return packet is from another IP on this subnet(XXX.XXX.XXX.125).
I think maybe there is another route or bridge in this link. 
Am i right?

Thanks

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful: What kind of ethernet packets are you observing (you are talking about a MAC address)? Obviously you are not using DSL. Which technology are you using? How did you find out the IP address "XXX.XXX.XXX.125"?

Comment: Is it ethernet and you got .125 and .126 from the ARP table?  If so, it's perfectly possible if a little unusual to have asymmetric routes.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jonathanjo, it a fiber leasedline wan,the problem that i can not report the inside bandwidth from this link because source and destination MAC are not the same. I can see both IPs on ARP table.

Comment: We do need some more detail to help: model and so on of the equipment, and if you show us some output you consider to be wrong/problematic.  Asymmetric routing isn't of itself normally a problem.

Comment: We use Array APV1600 load 3 leasedline WAN links connect to ISP fiber converter for internet, just 1 link have problem because Array can not caculate the inbound bandwith, but can caculate the outboud traffic only. Its caculate base on MAC address of gateway.

Comment: Possibly just that you're sending to a virtual IP (such as with HSRP or VRRP) in which case the return would come from the physical IP that is active in the HSRP/VRRP configuration.  If you can post the MAC addresses from the ARP entries it should answer that question.

Comment: How you're testing this? Are you pinging your gateway and the result come from another IP address (in this case ping should not work at all. Unless you're capturing your packets and even then if you use NAT this should not work(?) because the reply IP is different is from initial destination)

Comment: @RickSanch i captured packet by wireshark

Comment: @ToiLee Sure. Glad your mystery is solved